# Is it possible to create a serializer with all histories using django-simple-history?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-simple-history

I'm using django-simple-history to record activities in my models. My idea is having a serializer to aggregate all model's activities and a view to show this information with filters (per model and user).

Something like this  `...api/history/?table=example&user=2`, `...api/history/?table=another_example`

models

```py
class MyExampleModel(models.Model):
    ...
    history = HistoricalRecords()

class MyAnotherExampleModel(models.Model):
    ...
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

serializer

```py
class HistorySerializer():
    # with all records activities
```

views

```py
class HistoryViewSet():
    # with filter for model and user.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do this. It's just a matter of what data you would want to have in that serializer and how many database queries you want to make.

Each model's history is held in a separate table, so if you have *n* tables, then it would require *n* queries. In order to find all of the managers you need to query, you could run the following code block in your View:

```
from simple_history.exceptions import NotHistoricalModelError
from simple_history.utils import get_history_manager_for_model
from django.db import models

history_managers = []
for model in models.registered_models.values():
    # If you want to filter by which model you see, you could do that here. 
    try:
        history_managers.append(get_history_manager_for_model(model))
    except NotHistoricalModelError:
        continue
```

Now, with your list of `history_managers`, you can now create a list of filtered history objects to pass to your serializer (assuming at this point you have a `user_id` you want to filter on and:

```
history_objects = []
for manager in history_managers:
    history_objects += list(manager.objects.filter(history_user_id=user_id))

serializer = MyHistorySerializer(history_objects, many=True)
```

In terms of how you'll want to structure that serializer, you'll want to only use serializer fields that are consistent across all historical objects, like:

- `history_user_id`
- `history_id`
- `change_reason`
- `history_date`

Comment: Thanx a lot for your support. I have some issues... 1) What would the serializer look like, do you have any examples? 2) Running the view, I found `module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'registered_models'`

Answer (score 0):

You should try django.apps.apps.get_models(). 
The tables pattern is "Historical MyExampleModel"

```
from django.apps import apps

class HistoryListApi(generics.ListAPIView):
    history_managers = []
    for model in apps.get_models():
        if 'Historical' in model._meta.object_name:
            history_managers.append(model)

    history_objects = []
     for manager in history_managers:
          history_objects += list(manager.objects.all())
```